# Is Android 4.3 the same as 4.0.3?

Tags: android-versions

I came across a Google play app that says version 4.0.3 and up required and I have 4.1.  So do I have to upgrade because I rather not as my old apps ptobably will not work with 4.3.  My question is whether it's a typo and they meant to say 4.3 or is my OS 4.1 good enough?

Phone: S3

Comment: They are a bit confusing with their names sometimes. 4.0 is ice cream sandwich, 4.1 is jelly bean 4.2 is jelly bean, 4.3 is... jelly bean again, 4.4 is kitkat. It's a bit weird. They subdivide down again, eg KitKat had 4.4, then a patch making it 4.4.1 then another patch making it 4.4.2. There's no consistencly like the first number changing means a new code name or anything. Generally apps needing 4.0 and up use some feature introduced often Hardware Acceleration. However, some just set their app for that and higher just because really!

Comment: Maybe you want to set something as a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here, you can see the versions: [Wikipedia about Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29#Platform_usage)
4.0.x is older than 4.1.x and so on. [It's explained here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning)

Answer (score 1):

No, as 4.0.3 is Ice Cream Sandwich while 4.3 is Jelly Bean. What you saw was the version number of the application, not the needed version of Android.

I hope this helped!